# DST not accounted for in certain relative times

Tags: php, datetime, dst

Last Sunday the European Union switched from CET (+0100) to CEST (+0200). I'm writing code to apply an increment to a date and it isn't working properly because time zone transition is only properly taken into account with some relative formats:

- `'+x minutes'` omits the missing hour
- `'+x hours'` doesn't

Here's my test code:

```
echo 'Time zone database: ' . timezone_version_get() . PHP_EOL;
echo PHP_EOL;

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');

$start = new DateTime('2017-03-26 01:59:00');
$increments = array(
    '+2 minutes' => '2017-03-26 03:01:00',
    '+2 hours'   => '2017-03-26 04:59:00',
);

echo 'Start:        ' . $start->format('r') . PHP_EOL;
foreach ($increments as $increment => $expected_string) {
    echo '>>> ' . $increment . PHP_EOL;

    $expected_end = new DateTime($expected_string);
    $actual_end = clone $start;
    $actual_end->modify($increment);

    echo 'Expected end: ' . $expected_end->format('r') . PHP_EOL;
    echo 'Actual end:   ' . $actual_end->format('r') . PHP_EOL;
    echo ($expected_end->format('c')===$actual_end->format('c')  ? 'OK' : 'ERROR') . PHP_EOL;
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

([run online](https://3v4l.org/1Q4OK))

```
Time zone database: 2016.3

Start:        Sun, 26 Mar 2017 01:59:00 +0100
>>> +2 minutes
Expected end: Sun, 26 Mar 2017 03:01:00 +0200
Actual end:   Sun, 26 Mar 2017 03:01:00 +0200
OK

>>> +2 hours
Expected end: Sun, 26 Mar 2017 04:59:00 +0200
Actual end:   Sun, 26 Mar 2017 03:59:00 +0200
ERROR
```

Since [relative formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) are often so counter-intuitive I'm not sure whether I'm getting some documented behaviour or it's a bug.

Can you shed some light on it?

Comment: There are plenty of DST transition bugs reported https://bugs.php.net/search.php?cmd=display&order_by=id&direction=DESC&package_name%5B%5D=Date%2Ftime+related I am sure you can find something relevant.

Comment: @AlexBlex Yeah... At this point I'm pretty sure it's a PHP bug. Adding 60 minutes renders `03:59:00 +0200`, adding 61 renders `03:00:00 +0200`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't be a relative format misunderstanding because behaviour is erratic within the same format:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');

$start = new DateTime('2017-03-26 01:59:00');
$increments = array(
    '+60 minutes'   => '2017-03-26 03:59:00',
    '+61 minutes'   => '2017-03-26 04:00:00',
);

echo 'Start:        ' . $start->format('r') . PHP_EOL;
foreach ($increments as $increment => $expected_string) {
    echo '>>> ' . $increment . PHP_EOL;

    $expected_end = new DateTime($expected_string);
    $actual_end = clone $start;
    $actual_end->modify($increment);

    echo 'Expected end: ' . $expected_end->format('r') . PHP_EOL;
    echo 'Actual end:   ' . $actual_end->format('r') . PHP_EOL;
    echo ($expected_end->format('c')===$actual_end->format('c')  ? 'OK' : 'ERROR') . PHP_EOL;
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

([run online](https://3v4l.org/BidZS))

```
Start:        Sun, 26 Mar 2017 01:59:00 +0100
>>> +60 minutes
Expected end: Sun, 26 Mar 2017 03:59:00 +0200
Actual end:   Sun, 26 Mar 2017 03:59:00 +0200
OK

>>> +61 minutes
Expected end: Sun, 26 Mar 2017 04:00:00 +0200
Actual end:   Sun, 26 Mar 2017 03:00:00 +0200
ERROR
```

In other words, adding 61 minutes produces an earlier date than adding 60.

In short, **PHP does not handle time zone transitions properly**. There's an [issue ticket](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=74274) that acknowledges it and even an [RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/datetime_and_daylight_saving_time) from 2011 that analyses possible fixes.

<sup>(Credit goes to [@Alex Blex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1110423/alex-blex) for this information.)</sup>

It's worth noting that good old Unix-timestamp based functions are affected too:

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');

$start = strtotime('2017-03-26 01:59:00');
$increments = array(
    '+60 minutes'   => '2017-03-26 03:59:00',
    '+61 minutes'   => '2017-03-26 04:00:00',
);

echo 'Start:        ' . date('r', $start) . PHP_EOL;
foreach ($increments as $increment => $expected_string) {
    echo '>>> ' . $increment . PHP_EOL;

    $expected_end = strtotime($expected_string);
    $actual_end = strtotime($increment, $start);

    echo 'Expected end: ' . date('r', $expected_end) . PHP_EOL;
    echo 'Actual end:   ' . date('r', $actual_end) . PHP_EOL;
    echo ($expected_end===$actual_end ? 'OK' : 'ERROR') . PHP_EOL;
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

([run online](https://3v4l.org/bJlot))

```
Start:        Sun, 26 Mar 2017 01:59:00 +0100
>>> +60 minutes
Expected end: Sun, 26 Mar 2017 03:59:00 +0200
Actual end:   Sun, 26 Mar 2017 03:59:00 +0200
OK

>>> +61 minutes
Expected end: Sun, 26 Mar 2017 04:00:00 +0200
Actual end:   Sun, 26 Mar 2017 03:00:00 +0200
ERROR
```

## Workaround

Use UTC, of course :)

You can either use UTC internally for all calculations or switch to UTC before performing date maths. The latter (the most verbose case) implies something like:

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');

$start = new DateTime('2017-03-26 01:59:00');
$increments = array(
    '+60 minutes'   => '2017-03-26 03:59:00',
    '+61 minutes'   => '2017-03-26 04:00:00',
);

echo 'Start:        ' . $start->format('r') . PHP_EOL;
$local = $start->getTimezone();
$utc = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
foreach ($increments as $increment => $expected_string) {
    echo '>>> ' . $increment . PHP_EOL;

    $expected_end = new DateTime($expected_string);
    $actual_end = clone $start;
    $actual_end->setTimezone($utc);
    $actual_end->modify($increment);
    $actual_end->setTimezone($local);

    echo 'Expected end: ' . $expected_end->format('r') . PHP_EOL;
    echo 'Actual end:   ' . $actual_end->format('r') . PHP_EOL;
    echo ($expected_end->format('c')===$actual_end->format('c')  ? 'OK' : 'ERROR') . PHP_EOL;
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

([run online](https://3v4l.org/233hp))

```
Start:        Sun, 26 Mar 2017 01:59:00 +0100
>>> +60 minutes
Expected end: Sun, 26 Mar 2017 03:59:00 +0200
Actual end:   Sun, 26 Mar 2017 03:59:00 +0200
OK

>>> +61 minutes
Expected end: Sun, 26 Mar 2017 04:00:00 +0200
Actual end:   Sun, 26 Mar 2017 04:00:00 +0200
OK
```

If you use UTC everywhere you don't need any of this, just a final `->setTimezone()` when displaying to end user.